# latex expressions in 2 columns separated by line

Tags: latex3

I want to write latex code for the following --
[image]

i have the following latex code but it doesn't work --

```
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=customgray, linecolor=white]
\begin{align}
\texttt{output} := \code{existingAttribute} \, | \, \code{derivedAttribute} \\
\end{align}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.47\columnwidth-0.5em}
\centering
\begin{align}
\code{existingAttribute} := \code{attr \subseteq attribute} \\
\end{align}
\end{minipage}
\hfill

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3em}
\centering
\textcolor{black}{\rule{1pt}}
\end{minipage}

\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.47\columnwidth-0.5em}
\centering
\begin{align}
\code{derivedAttribute} := [\code{const} \, \code{ op } \, \code{attr}] \, | \, \code{exp} \\
\code{op} &\rightarrow + \, | \, - \, | \, * \, | \, / \\
\code{exp} &\rightarrow (\code{const} \, \code{ op } \, \code{attr})+ \, | \, (\code{attr} \, \code{ op } \, \code{attr})+
\end{align}
\end{minipage}

\end{mdframed}
```

I see it like this currently --
[image]

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: This looks like a job for paracol, but I have no idea what `\code` is supposed to do.

Comment: Highly unlikely you see it, as you posted with the code you wrote. Offhand you using a) align, so equation numbers would show.  Your rule take it out fully is wrong. 3) Use \fbox to enclose the minipages, so you will see the problem immediately! Please post a working MWE that is compilable; ie. starting from `\documentclass` and until `\end{document}. `